# Data from partitioned table does not show up when queried from Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, databricks

**Note that** this question **is not** a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476731/spark-sql-saveastable-returns-empty-result)! I do not use Spark SQL for partitioning! I am saving individual parquet files!

**I am also using Databricks** which does not support Hive-flavored SQL.

I have a table in Hive (I'm using Databricks) which contains two partitions. It looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo_test (`col0` STRING, `col1` STRING, `col2` STRING, `datestamp` STRING)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (
  `serialization.format` '1'
)
PARTITIONED BY (datestamp)
```

**Edit:** *this is also the result of calling `show create table foo_test;`

I've added two partitions with Spark to this table by hand:

```py
df = spark.read.csv(file_path.format(datestamp), header=True, inferSchema=True)

partitionPath = "/mnt/foo_test/datestamp={}/".format(datestamp)

df.coalesce(1).write.parquet(partitionPath, mode="overwrite")


/mnt/foo_test/datestamp=20180101/
/mnt/foo_test/datestamp=20180102/
```

If I load the data with Spark I can see it is there:

```py
spark.read.option("mergeSchema", True).parquet("/mnt/foo_test").show()

+----+----+----+----+---------+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|datestamp|
+----+----+----+----+---------+
| foo| bar| baz|   1| 20180102|
| xul| qux| wom|   2| 20180102|
| bar| foo| baz|   1| 20180102|
| qux| xul| wom|   2| 20180102|
| foo| bar| baz|null| 20180101|
| xul| qux| wom|null| 20180101|
| bar| foo| baz|null| 20180101|
| qux| xul| wom|null| 20180101|
+----+----+----+----+---------+
```

My problem is that if I run an SQL query against this Hive table it returns nothing:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo_test;

OK
```

Even after adding the partition by hand:

```py
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE foo_test ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (datestamp=20180102)")
```

and repairing the table:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE foo_test;
```

I can see that the partitions are present according to Hive:

```sql
SHOW PARTITIONS foo_test;

partition
datestamp=20180102
datestamp=20180101
```

but the `SELECT` returns nothing.

This is the description of my table:

```
col0    string  null
col1    string  null
col2    string  null
datestamp   string  null
# Partition Information     
# col_name  data_type   comment
datestamp   string  null
# Detailed Table Information        
Database    default 
Table   foo_test    
Owner   root    
Created Thu Apr 26 12:25:06 UTC 2018    
Last Access Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970    
Type    MANAGED 
Provider    parquet 
Table Properties    [transient_lastDdlTime=1524745506]  
Location    dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/foo_test  
Serde Library   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe 
InputFormat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat   
OutputFormat    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat  
Storage Properties  [serialization.format=1]    
Partition Provider  Catalog
```

**What could be the problem here?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL saveAsTable returns empty result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476731/spark-sql-saveastable-returns-empty-result) (See also the first answer here)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of said question. I am using Databricks as I have properly tagged in this question and it does not support Hive flavored SQL. @whomever downvoted: care to explain?

Comment: _I am using Databricks as I have properly tagged in this question and it does not support Hive flavored SQL_ - to extent which is required here it does, same as any other Spark application, with SparkSession initialized with Hive support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not setting the location in your `CREATE TABLE` definition, and you're not setting the location of the newly added partition.

In your table definition, you should define it as an external table and give it the path to your data, either as the `LOCATION` or `PATH` parameter. Then `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` should properly add the partitions.

For the `ALTER TABLE` command, you need to set the `LOCATION` parameter. In that snippet you are just telling the table "there's a partition date=20180102" without telling it where the data is.

per https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions

`spark.sql("ALTER TABLE foo_test ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (datestamp=20180102) location '/mnt/foo_test/datestamp=20180102/' ")`

Comment: `ADD PARTITION` without `LOCATION` is syntactically valid, and defaults to the root path, so `ALTER TABLE foo_test ADD PARTITION (datestamp=20180102)` should map `/user/hive/warehouse/foo_test/datestamp=20180102`.

Comment: Glad I could help @AdamArold

Answer (score 2):

> I do not use Spark SQL for partitioning!

I have to disagree. This is not a Hive table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_test (`col0` STRING, `col1` STRING, `col2` STRING, `datestamp` STRING)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (
  `serialization.format` '1'
)
PARTITIONED BY (datestamp)
```

It is a Spark table definition.

[Hive table definition would be](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual%2BDDL#LanguageManualDDL-PartitionedTables):

```
CREATE TABLE foo_test (`col0` STRING, `col1` STRING, `col2` STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (`datestamp` STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
```

So you do use Spark partitioning, and as already explained in [the question you've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476731/spark-sql-saveastable-returns-empty-result), and further in the [linked JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14927), Spark and Hive partitioning schemes are not compatible..

Note that both Hive and Spark are supported in `SparkSession.sql` as long as Hive support has been enabled, when `SparkSession` has been initialized (default on Databricks platform).

Also it is not clear why you write to `/mnt/foo_test/datestamp={}` here, which might another source of problems. If you want to use local file API (why would you?), Databricks mounts it by default on `/dbfs`.

Since you call `ADD PARTITIONS` without location, it uses root path for the table (`dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/foo_test` based on the `DESCRIBE` output), so if you decided to use local API, and use default configuration you should write to

```
/dbfs/user/hive/warehouse/foo_test/datestamp=20180102
```

If you use non-standard configuration it would be great if include it in your question.

Comment: So, you're basically saying this question is answered in the question that 's linked as _"not a duplicate of <X>"_?

Comment: @Cerbrus When you put it this way, then I guess I do :/ Maybe it would be better as comment? Although it is hard to put code there. Would you recommend I delete this? [Achyuth suggests there might be some other problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50045246/9613318) as well.

Comment: No, it is not answered. I am using Databricks as I have tagged in my question. The linked solution does not work since Databricks does not support running Hive flavored SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The Table defination is pointitng to different location

```
Location    dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/foo_test
```

It should point to the following location `/mnt/foo_test`

**Look for hive create table with location**

Comment: Sorry that's an artifact of using Databricks. The locations are fine.

Comment: can you please do the show create table table_name and update the question once. To make sure

Comment: Ok, wait a sec.

Comment: I've edited my answer to contain the result of the `show`.

Answer (score 0):

when you create your table in hive use:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_test (`col0` STRING, `col1` STRING, `col2` STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (`datestamp` STRING)
stored as PARQUET
location '/mnt/foo_test';
```

you can use with spark write with partition :

```
df.repartition($"datestamp").partitionBy("datestamp").write.parquet(partitionPath, mode="overwrite")
```

this will write to hive table with the partitionned path /mnt/foo_test/datestamp=***/.

i hope this will help