# unable to insert into hive partitioned table from spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I create an external partitioned table in hive.
in the logs it shows numinputrows. that means the query is working and sending data. but when I connect to hive using beeline and query, `select * or count(*)` it's always empty.

```scala
def hiveOrcSetWriter[T](event_stream: Dataset[T])( implicit spark: SparkSession): DataStreamWriter[T] = {

    import spark.implicits._
    val hiveOrcSetWriter: DataStreamWriter[T] = event_stream
      .writeStream
      .partitionBy("year","month","day")
      .format("orc")
      .outputMode("append")
      .option("compression", "zlib")
      .option("path", _table_loc)
      .option("checkpointLocation", _table_checkpoint)

    hiveOrcSetWriter
  }
```

What can be the issue? I'm unable to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL saveAsTable returns empty result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476731/spark-sql-saveastable-returns-empty-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msck repair table tablename
```

It give go and check the location of the table and adds partitions if new ones exits.

In your spark process add this step in  order to query from hive.

Answer (score 1):

Your streaming job is writing new partitions to the table_location. But the Hive metastore is not aware of this.

When you run a select query on the table, the Hive checks metastore to get list of table partitions. Since the information in Metastore is outdated, so the data don't show up in the result.

You need to run -

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> RECOVER PARTITIONS
```

command from Hive/Spark to update the metastore with new partition info.

Comment: @Sam can you check the answer and see if this works for you?

Comment: yup i checked ALTER TABLE was not working for me but msck repair command worked.